# NodeJS Async: callback allready called?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I am getting this error:

```
node:19100) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Callback was already called.
```

On my async.each call, it seems like it is trying to call "done()" more then once per "circuit" but I don't understand why, i though that once the async callback is called the function would exit ?

Circuits is an array of String containing ids. I am simply trying to loop through them to execute async calls to database on each.

```
var getTimeseriesForCircuit = function(circuits, to, from, callback){
    if (!validateDates(from, to)) {
        return callback(400, 'Invalid date(s)');
    }

    var validJSON = false;
    try {
        circuits = JSON.parse(circuits);
        validJSON = true;
    }
    catch (e) {
        return callback(500, e);
    }

    if (validJSON) {
        async.each(circuits, function (circuitID, done) {
            var frequency = getFrequencyFromRange(from, to);
            var influxFromDate = from * 1000000;
            var influxToDate = to * 1000000;

            getVoltageGatewayID(null, circuitID, function (gatewayID) {
                getVoltageFromInflux(null, influxFromDate, influxToDate, gatewayID, frequency, function (voltage) {
                    getMeanAmpsFromInflux(null, influxFromDate, influxToDate, circuitID, frequency, function (data) {
                        if (JSON.stringify(data) != []) {
                            var timeWithPower = calculatePower(data, voltage);
                            return done(null, {'circuitID': circuitID, data: timeWithPower});
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        }, function (err, results) {
            if (err) {
                return callback(500, err)
            } else {
                return callback(200, results)
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        return callback(400, 'The circuits sent were not in a valid format');
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean in the first sentence. Can you explain what you mean with that?

Comment: You are calling callback potentially 3 times: once if `validateDates(from, to)` is false, and twice if `JSON.parse()` throws an error.

Comment: My bad my question was unclear, I updated it, the error is in the async call not in the rest of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to call your async callback "done" without return:

```
done(null, {'circuitID': circuitID, data: timeWithPower});
```

and on error something like this:

```
done('errormessage');
```

so you get your result in the "final"callback after your each

see [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each)

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing return statement in function.

When you catch or have an error instead of just `callback()` use `return callback()`. 
This will prevent execution of code bellow return statements and error that you see.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My bad my question was unclear I have updated it, the error comes from the asycn.each call not the rest of the function.